# How to get the width / height of an element in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This is something I always wondered about but never really asked.
Say I have a rectangle box, image or other element in photoshop, when I make the desired element active and I check the info panel, The width / height never shows up - Should it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you make a selection, the 'Info' panel should show the width (W:) and height (H:) of the selection. It has to be the active selection, though.

*Note: The active selection "marching ants" don't show up in the screen capture.*

[image]

Comment: …and you can select the contents of any layer by command+clicking it in the Layers palate.

Comment: Thanks Robert, How do I make the active selection, I assume I don't just click it?

Comment: I used the Magic Wand tool but there are other ways, like @SidneySM's suggestion above.

Answer (score 13):

If you activate the transform tool on a layer (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), you'll see that in the top panel, the X/Y position is shown along-side the size, angle, etc.

The size is in *Percent* by default, but right-clicking the field gives you a selection of measurements to pick from, *Pixels*, in this case.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Press 'Command-T' to transform the current layer. That will also show it's width and height in the info panel, as per Robert's answer (but more convenient).